# How do I do source code management without version control tools?

Tags: version-control

I work on a software project which has a suite of source code that undergoes periodic change. The code is typically promoted to a production environment, and development continues in a development environment. Emergency hotfixes in production need to be backported to development. A third environment for testing may also exist from time to time. Many developers work on this code at the same time, often needing to make changes to the same individual file.

In short, a classic use-case for version control software. Unfortunately, we have a stone age IT department, and we do all our development in a stock Windows XP environment with absolutely no possibility of using any other software without approval - which never happens. We are lucky to have Winzip.

**So what's the best way of managing the above workflow without any real tools?** At the moment we are just editing files on a Windows shared drive, making ad-hoc working copies into folders with names like "James's Copy of X", doing backups with Winzip, and calling across the room, "is anybody working on this file at the moment?"

Thanks,
James

Edit: Some clarifications:

The irony is that the system is hardly locked down at all - I could download, install and configure TortoiseHg in about 7 minutes. But I need to do this by the book.

I am also actively pursuing getting version control software through official channels, but ETA for that is 6-9 months if ever, so I'm just trying to do the best I can with what I have *now*.

Finally, trust me, you will be reading about this project on TheDailyWTF one day, so please help me out with what *I* can do *now* rather than what management should have done last week.

Comment: Fire the IT department.

Comment: Do you have any kind of web access? FTP access? Any of the standard built-in WinXP command-line tools? Exactly how "locked down" is locked down - if you were to sneak a copy of svn.exe into C:\Windows\System32, would anyone notice?

Comment: Find a new job with a good company... any company other than that one.  Quickly.  Right now.  Seriously.  Go.

Comment: In all seriousness - if you're backporting changes from production and collaborating via ZIP files due to management restrictions, your employers are voluntarily accepting so much unnecessary cost - not to mention risk to business continuity - that their shareholders could probably sue them for negligence.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584071/tips-for-coding-using-hostile-tools related to the same applcation and environment?

Comment: Dylan, not quite the same, but broadly speaking yes.

Comment: "I am also actively pursuing getting version control software through official channels, but ETA for that is 6-9 months if ever, so I'm just trying to do the best I can with what I have now."  Good on you for taking a little initiative but I'd be wary of implementing something without approval in what is clearly a very draconian IT dept.  If I were you I'd expend this energy in looking for a job elsewhere.  The fact that you're on SO pro-actively looking for a way to get the job done better without mgt support suggests to me you're time and skills would be better spent/appreciated elsewhere!

Comment: By way of update, I have now succeeded in getting Sourcegear Vault implemented! It's a infinite improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, two actual options occur to me here.

First. You have Winzip, and you appear to have web access since you're posting on Stack Overflow. Assuming you have the ability to upload files (which isn't a given, since you're still using a generic StackOverflow avatar) you could find - or build - an externally-hosted service that'll allow you to upload a ZIP file via a web browser, unzip it, and then commit the unzipped contents to a Git or Subversion repository. Stick a secure web front end on it (Apache + mod-dav-svn) and you'll have the ability to browse, review and commit changes to individual files. You won't get the benefits of local SVN/GIT capabilities like merging, but you'll have centralized project history. There could even be a quite lucrative business model in this - selling web-based SCM to developers who are stuck on IE6 and WinXP and can't install *anything*.

Second: You find a junior/admin in your IT team who's just as frustrated as you are at the draconian restrictions being enforced, persuade them that you know what you're doing, and get them to 'accidentally' set up a local administrator account on your workstation. WinXP is sufficiently insecure out of the box that this shouldn't be too hard to make this look like an accident.

Comment: You could EVEN try mapping a WinXP drive letter to a WebDAV folder that's actually a DAV front end to a Subversion repo... that way committing your changes just means "copy everything to drive W:" and Subversion will track revision history for you...

Comment: Outsourcing sounds like an intriguing idea - I will certainly pursue that alongside the long-term project of getting local software authorized - mod_dav_svn with autoversioning as described here (http://oreilly.com/opensource/excerpts/9780596510336/webdav-and-autoversioning.html) sounds like an excellent technical workaround, but there's then the question of getting permission to upload code to a third party...

Answer (score 8):

Get source control. Talk to management, refuse to work, do whatever you can to get it in.

Bring in a netbook, install a SVN server and use that. Run Git off USB drives.

Really - anything.

It is not just an *industry standard* now - it is irresponsible of you and your management to continue working like this.

---

After notifying management and explaining that this is an issue, if they do nothing, just let the inevitable happen. Something that shouldn't have been promoted to production will be (regression, bug, new feature, whatever). When they come to blame you, explain how source control can help ensure that such things do not happen again. Perhaps they will listen then.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage as much of the disruptive behavior but I would certainly make sure there's a record of your protestation so that when bad things do happen, they know that you warned them.

Comment: @Ishpeck - I am trying to drive the point home... Not having source control is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the files into a seperate folder and call that folder vers_x, or get the windows backup utility to save them each day, or another backup utility to do the same? though the first post is correct, strike till vers cont is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Get git. git init on the current source "repository". Install git on everyone's pc's.
Also, the strike idea is definitely not so bad in this case.